# C# Equilavent of "dynamic" JavaScript object?

Tags: c#

I want to create a single object (possibly Dictionary) with string keys that will have different variable types as the value (string, int, bool, Dictionary<string,string> etc). Is this possible?

*I understand this might just be a fundamental difference of two languages AKA square peg round hole

Comment: You mean like `Dictionary<string, object>`? Or if you know the names and variable types beforehand declaring a `class` would probably be better.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netcore-3.1. The problem is that you have to deal with casting, or it blows up. You can also do Dictionary<string,object>

Comment: If you want dynamic type support similar to JavaScript then you could use an [`ExpandoObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: @JoeSewell I tried Dictionary<string, object> but I wasn't able to figure out how to access the Dictionary<string,string> that I assigned to the "object" of the "parent" Dictionary<string,object> after I assigned it

Comment: @thefastlane - you need to cast the value back to a string. e.g. `(string)myDictionary["myKey"]` or maybe you mean `(Dictionary<string, string>)myDictionary["myKey"]`

Comment: @Greg That's what I needed! Seems really obvious now. Thanks! For whatever reason I couldn't seem to come to that solution via searching online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` as values type, that match better than `object` to the question and you need no future castings:

```
  var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

  dictionary.Add("1", 10);
  dictionary.Add("2", "test");
  dictionary.Add("3", true);

  foreach ( var item in dictionary )
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} is type: {item.Value.GetType().Name} = {item.Value}");

  Console.WriteLine();

  int v = dictionary["1"] + 10;
  Console.WriteLine(v);

  string s = dictionary["2"] + " one";
  Console.WriteLine(s);

  bool b = !dictionary["3"];
  Console.WriteLine(b);
```

*Output*

```
1 is type: Int32 = 10
2 is type: String = test
3 is type: Boolean = True

20
test one
False
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic

Answer (score 2):

A `Dictionary<string, object>` is roughly equivalent to an object in JavaScript.

Example:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
  "myString" = "helloWorld",
  "myChild" = new Dictionary<string, object>
  {
    "myName" = "bobby tables"
  }
};

var myString = (string)dictionary["myString"];
var myName = (string)((Dictionary<string, object>)dictionary["myChild"])["myName"];
```

You can also use the `dynamic` keyword and `ExpandoObject`.

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.MyString = "helloWorld";
obj.MyChild = new ExpandoObject();
obj.MyChild.MyName = "bobby tables";

string myString = obj.MyString;
string myName = obj.MyChild.MyName;
```

Comment: I'm going to implement your answer because I like the idea of casting the type before I use the variable. However Olivier did technically answer my original question. Thanks again!